# Why 'redis-cli monitor' command output only 'OK'?

Tags: redis, magento-1.7

I'm try to setup redis on my local project which running on magento 1.7
I follow this [article](https://cloudkul.com/blog/configure-magento-1-9-x-with-redis-as-backend-cache/) , do all steps:

1. install redis server:

> sudo apt-get install redis-server

2. created Cm_RedisSession.xml, added content to it:

> ```
> <config>
>     <modules>
>         <Cm_RedisSession>
>             <active>true</active>
>             <codePool>community</codePool>
>         </Cm_RedisSession>
>     </modules>
> </config>
> ```

3.changed local.xml:

```
<!-- This is a child node of config/global -->
<cache>
  <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
  <backend_options>
    <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
    <port>6379</port>
    <persistent></persistent> <!-- Specify unique string to enable persistent connections. E.g.: sess-db0; bugs with phpredis and php-fpm are known: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/70 -->
    <database>0</database> <!-- Redis database number; protection against accidental data loss is improved by not sharing databases -->
    <password></password> <!-- Specify if your server requires authentication -->
    <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
    <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures; a value of 1 will not retry after the first failure -->
    <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration; phpredis does not currently support setting read timeouts -->
    <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
    <compress_data>1</compress_data>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
    <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
    <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
    <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf, lz4 (as l4z) and snappy -->
    <use_lua>0</use_lua> <!-- Set to 1 if Lua scripts should be used for some operations -->
  </backend_options>
</cache>
        <!--session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save-->

<session_save>db</session_save>
        <redis_session>                       <!-- All options seen here are the defaults -->
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>            <!-- Specify an absolute path if using a unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <password></password>             <!-- Specify if your server requires authentication -->
            <timeout>2.5</timeout>            <!-- This is the connection timeout, not the locking timeout -->
            <persistent></persistent>         <!-- Specify unique string to enable persistent connections. E.g.: sess-db0; bugs with phpredis and php-fpm are known: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/70 -->
            <db>0</db>                        <!-- Redis database number; protection from accidental loss is improved by using a unique DB number for sessions -->
            <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>  <!-- Set to 0 to disable compression (recommended when suhosin.session.encrypt=on); known bug with strings over 64k: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/issues/18 -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>              <!-- gzip, lzf, lz4 or snappy -->
            <log_level>1</log_level>               <!-- 0 (emergency: system is unusable), 4 (warning; additional information, recommended), 5 (notice: normal but significant condition), 6 (info: informational messages), 7 (debug: the most information for development/testing) -->
            <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>                 <!-- maximum number of processes that can wait for a lock on one session; for large production clusters, set this to at least 10% of the number of PHP processes -->
            <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>       <!-- seconds to wait for a session lock in the frontend; not as critical as admin -->
            <fail_after>10</fail_after>                          <!-- seconds after which we bail from attempting to obtain lock (in addition to break after time) -->
            <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
            <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime>                 <!-- Lifetime of session for non-bots on the first write. 0 to disable -->
            <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>          <!-- Lifetime of session for bots on the first write. 0 to disable -->
            <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>                    <!-- Lifetime of session for bots on subsequent writes. 0 to disable -->
            <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>                 <!-- Disable session locking entirely. -->
            <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>                      <!-- Set the minimum session lifetime -->
            <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>                 <!-- Set the maximum session lifetime -->
        </redis_session>
```

4.clear cache and session folders

5.restart redis:

```
service redis-server restart
```

After that I type in terminal :

```
redis-cli monitor
```

And it output me only :

```
OK
```

But must be something like that:

```
OK
1460100081.165665 [0 127.0.0.1:51706] "set" "foo" "bar"
1460100083.053365 [0 127.0.0.1:51707] "get" "foo"
```

So I afraid in my case cashing is not generating.

Comment: It seems like the redis-cli got disconnected or the server can't send data back to the cli

Comment: @Guy Korland I checked if redis-server is working by command 'redis-cli ping' and getting response 'PONG' , so server is working.

Answer (score 1):

The MONITOR command works like what the word meaning itself, it output the commands that the Redis instance currently execuing.

So, you can execut some commands in another terminal, then you will see them appear in your "monitor" terminal.